# How to use op/3 inside a file

Tags: prolog

I try to define operator in a file using `op/3`. Like so

```
is_in(Thing, Place):-
  location(Thing, Place).

op(35, xfx, is_in).
```

But when I `consult/1` file in repl, I get an exception

```
No permission to modify static procedure `op/3'
```

I tried to use `dynamic` directive, but it results in the same error.

Executing `op(35, xfx, is_in).` in repl works.

Comment: `op/3` is a directive, so requires syntax `:- op(....).` in a file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to redefine `op/3` predicate instead of declaring a new operator.

To declare a new operator when consulting a file you have to add a directive in your program:

```
:-op(35, xfx, is_in).
```

Note that the operator will not be available before the directive, so you should add the directive above its usage within the file.

Comment: The other option is to use the module export list when defining a module. Probably not relevant for OP.